# Why does Rails delete method get routed to GET instead of DELETE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I am getting, the following routing error, i am not sure why it is not routing to DELETE and goes to GET

```
No route matches [GET] "/signout"
```

html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
```

routes.rb:

```
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

What command am i missing?

Comment: Double check if your JavaScripts are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to ensure you have the `jquery_ujs` file loaded as part of your `application.js` manifest. I believe in older versions of Rails it is known as `rails_ujs`.

---

#### application.js

```
// ...
//= require jquery_ujs
// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if you load [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js) and allow javascript in your browser.

---

```
<%= link_to "link", some_path, method: "delete" %>
```

will generate

```
<a href="some/path" data-method="delete">link</a>
```

As soon as you click the link, jquery-ujs will cancel the action and [make a delete request](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js#L159), taken from the data-method attribute:

---

from [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to):
*:method => symbol of HTTP verb - This modifier will dynamically create an HTML form and immediately submit the form for processing using the HTTP verb specified. Useful for having links perform a POST operation in dangerous actions like deleting a record (which search bots can follow while spidering your site). Supported verbs are :post, :delete and :put. Note that **if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET**.*